# Prevent JQuery Datatables from keeping old data in the table after being destroyed

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, knockout.js, datatables

Good day

*Painting the scenario:*
I have a scenario I am working on for work, where I had to freeze the header row and first column on larger tables. I have utilized the `jquery Datatables` plugin with its `fixedColumns` extension to be able to do so

The table that I am working on also happens to have `knockout.js` bindings, which renders the `<tbody>` rows from data obtained in the page's typescript.

*the issue*
When I do a pull from the server to get the data from the table, on page refresh or on interactions with other controls on the page, I run the following code (be warned, it's quite ugly - just trying to get it to work now):

```
module dataTable {
export class dataTableClass {
    applyTable(tableIdString: string) : void {
        (<any>$(tableIdString))
            .DataTable({
                scrollY: 1000,
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                fixedHeader: true,
                fixedColumns: {
                    leftColumns: 1
                }
            });
    }

    dataTableExists(tableIdString: string): boolean {
        return (<any>$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(tableIdString));
    }

    applyDatatableIfTableExists(retryCount: number, elementId: string): void {
        if (!elementId) {
            console.warn("table id not defined.");
            return;
        }

        if (!retryCount) {
            retryCount = 0;
        } else if (retryCount > 100) {
            console.warn("could not convert table to dataTable.");
            return;
        }

        window.setTimeout(() => {
            var tableIdString = "#" + elementId;
            if ((<any>$(tableIdString)).length <= 0) {
                this.applyDatatableIfTableExists(++retryCount, elementId);
            } else {
                if (this.dataTableExists(tableIdString)) {
                    debugger;
                    (<any>$(tableIdString)).DataTable({ retrieve: true }).destroy(); // <-- issue here. it seems to restore old data to the now-datatable-less table
                }

                window.setTimeout(() => {
                    this.applyTable(tableIdString);
                    if (!this.dataTableExists(tableIdString)) {
                        this.applyDatatableIfTableExists(++retryCount, elementId);
                    }
                }, 250);    

                if (!(<any>$(tableIdString)).hasClass(".dataTable")) {
                    (<any>$(tableIdString)).addClass(".dataTable");
                }
            }
        }, 250);
    }


    applyDataTable(id) {
        this.applyDatatableIfTableExists(0, id);
    }
}
```

}

1. On server pull, in typescript, when the deferred code resolves and sets the table's data on an knockout observable array, the `applyDataTable` class gets called with the table's html ID
2. all the code runs fine for the first time - I allow the browser some time to render the table and to convert the table into a DataTable
3. When a user interacts with other controls on the page (to set filters for the knockout Observable array to change the table's contents), I destroy the table - presuming the table has already been initialised.
4. I recreate the table with the same DataTable options immediately after that so that new data (theoretically) displays in the table, having the `fixedColumns` extension render correctly again (since it changes cells and table header cells into tables of their own and apply css to make it look neat)

The issue comes on the line I marked. What happens on-screen is that it definitely removes the changes applied by DataTables from the HTML, but, the table that renders has old data in it (even though I fetched new data from the server by changing my search criteria on page - which generates new ....).

Also commenting out all this code inside my applyDataTable() method, it never sets the datatable plugin on my html table (as expected) and changing my filters reflects the newest and correct data on my table.

**So in tl;dr - what is happening is that some state information gets stored by datatables. is there a way for me to clear this state and only apply a datatable with my settings over my html table?**

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the old data from table body or the whole table. It depends on whether you're recreating column headers later.

For example:

```js
$('#example').DataTable().destroy();
$('#example tbody').empty();
```

So in your case it would be something like:

```js
(<any>$(tableIdString)).DataTable().destroy();
(<any>$(tableIdString + ' tbody')).empty();
```

Comment: Ah thanks. Will give this a go on Monday when I am at my workstation. Took a day off